# Titanium compatibility with Android 7

Tags: android, matrix, titanium, compatibility

I can read in https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+Compatibility+Matrix
Android is only supported until 6.0.x

What hasppens with android 7.0 ? Is supported? I´ve made several apps and crash with this version.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Apps build with Titanium work on Android 7. If it crashes for you perhaps you're using API's that are deprecated and removed on Android 7.

Furthermore you cannot compile apps using SDK 24/25, the maximum supported SDK is 23, but that doesn't mean apps won't work on higher SDK's.

A likely scenario your app crashed is because you're trying to use a feature that requires a permission. But in that case the app most likely also crashes on Android 6. If you have a more specific error, or actually a crash log a more specific answer can be given but that calls for a new question on SO